# In PHP i'm not getting desire id it's returning me as 0

Tags: php, null, return, zero

here is my piece of code
 i'm encountering a problem,,, below are my subject and test table in database. when i select a subject from dropdown menu on the" ADDTEST.php" page and want to add in Test table it couldn't get sub_id from "Subject Table " and it take "Sub_id" as 0 ...
'ADDTEST.PHP'

```
<td>Select Subject</td> 
<td><select name="sub_id">
<?php
include ("database.php");
$rs=mysql_query("Select * from mst_subject");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
$sub_id=$row['sub_id'];
?>
<option> <? echo $row['sub_name']; ?></option>
<?
}
?> </select>
<?php
include ("database.php");
if($_POST[submit]=='Save' || strlen($_POST['sub_id'])>0 )
{
$testname=$_POST['test_name'];
$totque=$_POST['totque'];
$sub_id=$_POST['sub_id'];
mysql_query("insert into mst_test(sub_id,test_name,total_que) values
('$sub_id','$testname','$totque')") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<p align=center>Test <b>\"$testname\"</b> Added Successfully.</p>";
unset($_POST);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Warning **Mysql_** is **deprecated** and will be **removed** in future versions of PHP. Please consider migrating to **Mysqli_** or  **PDO**. Furthermore, your data is **unescaped** and you are **Wide open** to **Sql Injection**. Please consider using **prepared statements**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace

```
<option> <? echo $row['sub_name']; ?></option>
```

with

```
<option value="<? echo $sub_id; ?>"> <? echo $row['sub_name']; ?></option>
```

In `$_POST['sub_id']` you get the value attribute(s) of the `select` -> `option` tags.

Please consider also moving from `mysql_` php functions to `mysqli` or `pdo`, if possible since `mysql_` is marked in php as deprecated and, even from my own experience, may occur problematic and too  limited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<option value="<?=$sub_id?>"><?=$row['sub_name']?></option>
```

Instead of

```
<option> <? echo $row['sub_name']; ?></option>
```